# How to get change request in nestjs middleware?

Tags: node.js, typescript, passport.js, nestjs, passport-jwt

I am trying to integrate passport in NestJS and to get current auth info anywhere using a decorator. My NestJs version was so old, I updated the NestJS version and changed to the code below. After I changed middleware code, I can no longer get current auth info.

How to get auth info using the changed middeware?

Code before changing the middleware:

```
 export class authMiddlware implements NestMiddleware {
  async resolve(): Promise<MiddlewareFunction> {
    return async (req, res, next) => {
      passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }, (err, user, info) => {

        if (err) {
          return next(err);
        }

        if (user) {
          req.user = user;
        }

        return next();
      })(req, res, next);
    };
  }
```

After changing the middleware:
In `passport.authenticate` I can get the changed user from the request, but out of passport, I cannot get the user from the request.

```
 @Injectable()
 export class authMiddlware implements NestMiddleware {
   use(req: Request, res: Response, next: Function) {
      passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }, (err, user, info) => {

        if (err) {
          return next(err);
        }

        if (user) {
          req.user = user;
        }

        console.log(req.user)

        next();
      })(req, res, next);

      console.log(req.user)
    };
  }
```

The user.decorator:

```
export const passUser= createParamDecorator((data, req) => {
  return plainToClass(User, req.user);
});
```

Comment: What version of Nest are you coming from and going to? Nest middleware no longer has a `resolve` method but a single `use` method in general.

Comment: I used Version of Nest is v5 and update to v7.

Comment: Is there a reason to not use the `AuthGuard` as shown in the [Authentication docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/authentication)?

Comment: I don't use `@nestjs/passport`. So, I'm trying to approach in another way.

Comment: what if there is a middleware that needs to be executed after the AuthGuard? @JayMcDoniel

Comment: Then use an interceptor or a pipe